# Почему у крупных сайтов столько много div вхождений

Tags: html, вконтакте, facebook, youtube, twitter

Почему у крупных сайтов таких как YouTube, VK, Facebook, Twitter очень много div вхождений, прям очень много, может доходить вплоть до 20, скажите для адаптации сайта? Но все-же очень много, можно же сделать куда проще, может кто объяснит почему так?

Если кто не понял что я имел ввиду под словом "множество вхождений"
[image: Вот картинка]

Comment: _> можно же сделать куда проще_ откуда такие мысли? Вы пробовали?

Comment: Потому что, их генерируют движки, а не пишут люди.

Comment: можешь сделать проще - сделай

Comment: @AlexR. _> Потому что, их генерируют движки, а не пишут люди_ ни один сайт из списка вроде не генерируется движком. Используют фреймворки? Да. Движки? Нет

Comment: Да было дело пробовал

Comment: Что? Ты о чем? я задал конкретный вопрос по этому поводу, потому что мне интересно, а ты отвечаешь так, как буд-то проще сделать не возможно

Comment: Что? Причем тут движки? Ты о чем вообще?

Comment: добавь описание, что ты имеешь ввиду под _много div вхождений_, пример такого кода. Попробуй сделать то же самое, чтобы сравнить, сколько _div вхождений_ получилось бы у тебя. Почему ты думаешь, что это на самом деле _очень много_?

Comment: я уже делал, у меня получилось куда меньше, на много меньше, и прекрасно все  работало

Comment: это называется "вложенность", а не "вхождение". Не думаю, что на указанных сайтах вкладываются пустые дивы :-) Я имел ввиду конкретный кусок, с конкретного сайта

Answer (score 0):

Это нужно для дизайна и JS. Взять например [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), вместе с ним идет титанический объем стилей. Хочешь выделить отдельный блок - создай div с таким-то классом. Внутри блока нужен заголовок - создай div с другим классом. Нужен в этом блоке текст - div, меню - div и так далее. Т.е. это во многом вопрос наследования опций отображения или сочетания таких правил. Разделяй и властвуй так сказать;

Иногда div-блоки нужны не для красивой разметки, а для AJAX-технологий. Скажем есть модальное окно, но текст в модальном окне должен меняться, как быть? Окружить блок с текстом с помощью div и задать id. Далее с помощью JavaScript можно найти div блок с нужным id и заменить его содержимое

Comment: К сожалению ты не понял суть вопроса

Comment: Или вы не поняли суть ответа. Дело в том крупные компании используют стили css. Стили для кнопок, стили для меню, для текста и так далее. Овер-дофига div'ов нужно чтобы в разном участке были разные стили и везде все выглядело однообразно. Можно сделать меньше div'ов в странице, но каждый такой div описать отдельно в css. Такой дизайн будет сложно поддерживать

Comment: Может я ошибаюсь в том что сделать проще нельзя, не получиться, или это не возможно

Comment: Можно сделать проще, да. Большое количество div-ов это способ упорядочить разработку, сделать ее более понятной. Если можете писать коротко - пишите, это хорошо, когда написано коротко, просто писать коротко не всегда возможно